# Getting rid of extra placeholders when serializing/deserializing a map of json using Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I am trying to serialize/deserialize a nested Map of Json string using Gson library.
The issue is, it is creating an extra place holder key("empMap")in the final Json .

Is there a way to get rid of this extra place holder key? I am sharing the pojo classes that I am using below.

Json that I am getting:

```
{
  "empMap": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Alex",
      "dob": {
        "year": 1990,
        "month": 1,
        "day": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Json that I want:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Alex",
    "dob": {
      "year": 1990,
      "month": 1,
      "day": 1
    }
  }
```

The pojos that I am using:
Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
 
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate dob;
 
    public Employee(Long id, String name, LocalDate dob) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

MappedJson.java (Final Json)

```
public class MappedJson {
    private Map<String, Employee> empMap;

    public MappedJson(Map<String, Employee > empMap) {
        super();
        empMap = empMap;
    }

    public Map<String, Employee > getEmpMap() {
        return empMap;
    }

    public void setPageMap(Map<String, Employee > empMap) {
        this.empMap = empMap;
    }
}
```